# Tkinter Checkbuttons' values won't change

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a program where you're able to choose events and then print said chosen events. I'm using checkbuttons to show from a list of events in titles. But I'm unable to change the value from each checkbutton in order to validate which event that will be printed.

I've tried to assign `IntVar()` variable and still isn't working and when I print the value of the checkbutton using `get()` it prints zero, even though the checkbuttons are checked in which it should return 1. Below is a part of my program that includes a small part of my main window and the create checkbutton window function.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Variables 
titles = ["soccer match","Basketball match","running", "Table Tennis", "paintball", "chess match"] 
button_list = []

#Button to get all the values from checkbuttons
def done_press():
    global button_list
    for title_index in range(len(titles)):
        print(button_list[title_index].get()) 

#Checkbutton window
def checkbutton():
    check_window = Tk()
    for x in range(len(titles)):
        button_list.append(IntVar()) 
        l = Checkbutton(check_window, text=titles[x], variable=button_list[x])
        l.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    done = Button(check_window, text ="Done", command=done_press)
    done.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

#Main Window
button = Button(root,text = "click me!",command= checkbutton)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What should I change in order to make each checkbutton return 1 as its variable if checked?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine except one tiny part:

```
check_window = Tk()
```

This creates another instance of `Tk`, and the two instances of Tk cannot pass variables between one another.

Simply change it to:

```
check_window = Toplevel()
```

Comment: It is more than just "not easy", it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Bryan. I thought it was just hard to do :)